# error: extern declaration of 'i' follows declaration with no linkage

Tags: c, declaration

In the following program, I thought that `extern int i;` will change the following `i` to refer to the `i` defined outside `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int i=1; // warning: 'i' initialized and declared 'extern'

int main()
{
    int i=2;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    extern int i; // error: extern declaration of 'i' follows declaration with no linkage
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason of the "error: extern declaration of 'i' follows declaration with no linkage", where "declaration with no linkage" refers to `int i=2;`?

After I remove `int i=2` in `main`,

- the error is gone,
- the warning "warning: 'i' initialized and declared 'extern'" on `extern int i=1;` also disappear . Why is that?

Thank you for explanations!

Comment: error at `extern int i;` : Duplicate identifiers in the same scope. Try `{ extern int i; printf("%d\n", i); }`

Comment: replace extern int i=1; with int i=1;

Comment: You already have a local variable `i` in the `main()`; you can't get at the global one.  Local variables hide the global ones.  This is not C++ where you have the scope resolution operator to help.  And it's bad practice to shadow global variables (GCC will warn if you specify `-Wshadow`).  And it's worse practice to want to access both in a single function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Nice to know it is bad practice. My example is more for studying scope and linkage purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you define a variable named `i` inside your `main` function, the `i` at file scope is masked and cannot be accessed (unless you have its address).

When you later add the declaration `extern int i`, this conflicts with the local variable named `i` at the same scope since locals can't have external linkage.  It does **not** give you access to the global `i`.

When you remove the local `i`, the `extern int i` declaration matches up with the definition at file scope, so there is no error.  As for the warning on `extern int i=1;`, that did *not* go away for me on gcc 4.1.2, so that depends on the compiler.

Comment: Re “locals can't have external linkage”: Linkage is a property of identifiers, and identifiers in block scope certainly can have external linkage. The reason `int i=2; extern int i;` has a conflict is C 2018 (and 2011 and earlier) 6.7 3 gives the constraint that, if an identifier has no linkage (which the `i` in `int i-2;` satisfies), there shall be no more than one declaration of it in the same scope and namespace, with certain exceptions for typedef names and tags.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i=1;  // external variable

int main()
{
    int i=2;            // local variable
    printf("%d\n", i);  // print local variable i==2

    {
        extern int i;       // point to external variable
        printf("%d\n", i);  // print external variable i==1
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question: What is the reason of the "error: extern declaration of 'i' follows declaration with no linkage", where "declaration with no linkage" refers to int i=2;?**
Answer: We do not need to use the *extern* keyword here on line 3 when it is a single file in a program and there is no other file in the same program or other location on the same file where the variable *int i* has its definition. There are two main reasons we can use *extern* keyword in C:
 1. When we want to declare a variable explicitly/globally but without its definition.
 2. To make the variable globally visible from any other file in a multi-file program or other location of the same file (see Ihdina's exmaple for this scenario).
Compiling your code on my system I get the following error,
*error: extern declaration of 'i' follows non-extern declaration* . 
which totally makes sense that the compiler detects the *extern* on line 9 as a duplicate declaration of the same variable *int i* on line 7.

**Question: After I remove int i=2 in main,
the error is gone,
the warning "warning: 'i' initialized and declared 'extern'" on extern int i=1; also disappear . Why is that?**
Answer: After removing the *int i=2;* the error was gone on my system but still I have the following warning message:
*warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]* 
Basically my system (*Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)*) does not like the explicit initialization with *extern* keyword. So, you should modify your code as per Ihdina's answer which compiles without error.