# C++ block scope extern declaration linkage, confusing C++ standard explanation

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

Standards [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) (C++ 11 draft) and [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) (C++ 14 draft) both have the same paragraph.

> **§ 3.5 Program and linkage [basic.link]**
>
> ¶ 6
>
> The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a variable declared by a block scope extern
>   declaration have linkage. If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage having the same name and
>   type, ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope, the block scope declaration
>   declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If there is more than one such
>   matching entity, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope entity
>   receives external linkage. [ Example:
>
> ```
>  static void f();
>  static int i = 0; // #1
>  void g() {
>      extern void f(); // internal linkage
>      int i; // #2 i has no linkage
>      {
>          extern void f(); // internal linkage
>          extern int i; // #3 external linkage
>      }
>  }
> ```
>
> There are three objects named i
>   in this program. The object with internal linkage introduced by the
>   declaration in global scope (line #1), the object with automatic storage duration and no linkage introduced by the declaration on line #2
>   , and the object with static storage duration and external linkage introduced by the declaration on line #3.
>   — end example
>   ]

I feel something is wrong with the `i` object example, it does not support what is said in the paragraph before, right?
In my opinion it must be two `i` objects, one with internal linkage (#1 and #3) and one with no linkage (#2).
Am I correct? Is it a mistake in the standard, the example is wrong?

In contrast, standard [N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) (C++ 17 draft) put it more correctly, in my opinion.

> **§ 6.5 Program and linkage [basic.link]**
>
> ¶ 6
>
> The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a variable declared by a block scope
>   extern declaration have linkage. If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage having the same name and
>   type, ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope, the block scope declaration
>   declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If there is more than one such
>   matching entity, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope entity
>   receives external linkage. If, within a translation unit, the same entity is declared with both internal and
>   external linkage, the program is ill-formed. [ Example:
>
> ```
> static void f();
> static int i = 0; // #1
> void g() {
>     extern void f();
>     // internal linkage
>     int i; // #2: i has no linkage
>     {
>         extern void f(); // internal linkage
>         extern int i; // #3: external linkage, ill-formed
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Without the declaration at line #2, the declaration at line #3 would link with the declaration at line #1.
>   Because the declaration with internal linkage is hidden, however, #3 is given external linkage, making the
>   program ill-formed.
>   — end example
>   ]

## Some testing

```
static void f();
static int i = 10; // #1
void g() {
  extern void f(); // internal linkage
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  int i = 2; // #2 i has no linkage
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  {
    extern void f(); // internal linkage
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    extern int i; // #3 external linkage
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  g();
  return 0;
}
```

This code produces `10 2 2 10` in clang-5.0 with any of `-std` value from `c++-11, c++-14, c++17`.
What basically support the wording of C++ 11 and 14 drafts.
Apparently, this did not change to a compilation error with `c++17` value. Is clang not compliant with C++ 17 on this point?

Comment: Unrelated, but better use N3337 for C++11 and N4141 (or N4140) for C++14. The ones you used are intermediate drafts.

Comment: To me example does make sense: "the block scope declaration declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration", that is what happen with #3. Only the implementations of C++ 17 have not yet conformed to a new change, and still do what the previous standards are requesting.

Comment: possible dup if [Can't understand the declaration #3 in the Example of \[basic.link\]/6 C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29904114/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thank you for referencing this question. It is relevant, however, it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was issue 426:

> Is this really what we want? C99 has 6.2.2.7/7, which gives undefined behavior for having an identifier appear with internal and external linkage in the same translation unit. C++ doesn't seem to have an equivalent.
>
> […] The CWG decided that it would be better to make a program with this kind of linkage mismatch ill-formed instead of having undefined behavior.

That is, it was decided that if a name has linkage, it shall be consistent. Implementations probably haven't implemented this yet.

Comment: What do you think about C++-11 and C++-14 drafts, do you think the examples are wrong?

Comment: @Yuki No, the committee amended the actual rules of the language.

Comment: They amended the final versions of C++11 and C++14 standards?

Comment: @Yuki No, they changed the language rules for C++17 to something different than what they were back in C++14. Neither example is incorrect, they just correspond to different standards.

Comment: Yes, that is clear: the C++17 standard in this regard is different from post-C++17 standards. I am confused in regards of C++14,11 (their examples does not reflect what is written in the paragraph above it, in my opinion). You say the example from their correspond to different standards? Sorry, to be annoying, but now I am confused even more. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Yuki I see what you mean, but AFAICS, the local i shadows the global one, so the innermost declaration cannot be resolved to a previous one?

Comment: That is strange. But the paragraph says nothing about this kind of "shadowing" rules with local definitions (i.e. declarations with no linkage): "If there is a visible declaration of an entity **with linkage** having the same name and type ...  declares that same entity and **receives the linkage of the previous declaration**". The paragraph concerns the declarations only with linkage, and does not say anything about no linkage declarations (like they are off concerns here). And the real compiler test only supports this statement.

Comment: @Yuki **Visible** declaration. The outermost one is not, however, visible. See http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.hiding

Comment: Good catch, thanks. So basically the compilers implement it wrongly?

Comment: @Yuki Evidently.