# Why does `int x; extern int x;` not compile?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Why does

```
int main(){
  int x; // no linkage
  extern int x; 
  return 0;
}
```

return the "extern follows non-extern" error? Since the second declaration is in the same scope as the first, and the first has no `extern` storage-class (thus no linkage by 6.2.2.6 in the C standard), shouldn't the the second declaration cause `x` to have external linkage by 6.2.2.4?

Comment: Is there any point of doing this or are you just curious?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: extern declaration of 'i' follows declaration with no linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724358/error-extern-declaration-of-i-follows-declaration-with-no-linkage)

Comment: @klutt I am just curious. I was wondering if this might be because no linkage identifiers must refer to unique entities as in 6.2.2.2 but I am not sure.

Comment: @GuachoPerez `thus no linkage` This is your answer right there. The "extern" declaration directly conflicts with the "no linkage" premise, because "no linkage" is mutually exclusive with "external linkage".

Comment: @dxiv I get it. So any non-`extern` declaration in block scope would have no linkage and adding external linkage would conflict with that?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Right, [6.6.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#2) makes it clear that a name with no linkage can have none of the other internal/module/external linkage types.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you. I guess I just misinterpreted the "specifies no linkage" in 6.2.2.4 as specifying "no linkage" as opposed to not specifying either internal or external linkage.